# Set topology of $A=(2,3)\cup (4,5)$ .

Tags: general-topology

I'm bit confused on how to find accumulation points. Theory wise I know what they are and I could find them in other cases but I'm stuck on this set.. $A=(2,3) \cup (4,5)$.

Thanks :)

Comment: Are there any points of $\Bbb R$ that you are sure are (or are not) accumulation points of $A$?

Comment: I'm probably wrong but 2 and 5 at least.

Comment: Yes, $2$ and $5$ are both accumulation points: every open interval around $2$ contains points of $A$ different from $2$, and similarly for $5$. What about the points of $A$ itself? What about $3$ and $4$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is clear from the definition that, here, the points of $A$ are themselves accumulation points. Now, try to convince yourself that:

1. The points $2,3,4,5$ are also accumulation points;
2. The other points of $\mathbb{R}$ (that is, the members of $\mathbb{R} - ([2,3] \cup [4,5])$) are *not* accumulation points.

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't sure! If A were (2,3)U(3,5),accumulation pts would have been [2,5]?

Comment: @Nour Yes, you got it.